# resend confirmation mail error Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Devise::ConfirmationsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, authentication, send

### Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Devise::ConfirmationsController#create

### 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

I am using the gem 'devise'.

to send confirmation email with gmail account.

but, the error in title occur.

I searched many cases similar to my case and tried solutions in there, but those perfectly not worked, so I think my error has some different origin

### ( what I tried is : 1. less securing myaccount.google.com/u/1/security 2. http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

development.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :authentication => :plain,
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => "mail.google.com",
    :user_name => ENV["******@gmail.com"],
    :password => ENV["******"],
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'localhost:3000'}
```

top most error line in error page

```
def check_response(res)
  unless res.success?
    raise res.exception_class, res.message
  end
end
```

please help me... TT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem your gmail setting, you should remove the ENV as you put string directly to it (as my understanding this is your local development this will generate an error since you also put config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :authentication => :plain,
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => "mail.google.com",
    :user_name => "******@gmail.com",
    :password => "******",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. it work!!!
Would you explain what local development means?
and relation with ENV...

Comment: ENV is usually using in production , in production we don't put the password directly into this file, we put the password in OS system variabel to make it save and how rails access OS system variabel is using ENV, this http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html may be can help you more to understand